# The Normalization of vehicle data

Tags: sql, database, database-design, normalization

I am starting University in September and looking to do some revision over the summer to help with the course. I am wondering if anyone could spare some time and help me with the Normalization of my Database. I am relatively new to this and I would graciously appreciate any help!

Here is the table I began with:

```
ABI_CODE  INT             <Unique Identifier
MOTOR_TYPE  VARCHAR       <Car, Bike or Van
MAKE  VARCHAR             <Renault, Ford etc.
MODEL  VARCHAR            <Focus, Fiesta etc.
MANUFACTURED_FROM  INT    <start year
MANUFACTURED_TO  INT      <end year
ENGINE_CC  INT            <999, 1199 etc.
ENGINE_TYPE  VARCHAR      <Diesel, Petrol or Electric
TRANSMISSION  VARCHAR     <Manual or Automatic
```

This is where I am so far:

```
Type ( MOTOR_TYPE )

Make ( MAKE )

Model ( ABI_CODE, MODEL, MANUFACTURED_FROM, MANUFACTURED_TO, ENGINE_CC )

Engine_Type ( ENGINE_TYPE )

Transmission ( TRANSMISSION )
```

If any more information could help someone to help me then please ask and I will update this post.

EDIT: SHOWING THE RELATIONS

One Make can have Many Models

One Model can have One Motor_type, Engine_Type, Manufactured_From, Manufactured_To, Engine_CC, Transmission

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: this is an exercise of your own making, or does it come from a course you had before?

Comment: You still have no references to `transmission` and `make`. Also a `model` should not have a reference to `manufactured_from` and `manufactured_to`; they are in the same table at the moment (which is fine). 
Your relations would be more clear if you add `id`-fields to your tables and base the references on table name and reference field.

Comment: Putting engine_cc in the model table looks like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would everywhere add an unique identifier, to properly make the specific relations.

At last, your data model would look like this:

```
Model ( MODEL_ID (PK), ABI_CODE, MODEL, MANUFACTURER_ID (FK), 
ENGINE_ID (FK), MOTOR_TYPE, Transmission, MAKE)

ManuFacturer (MANUFACTURER_ID, MANUFACTURED_FROM, MANUFACTURED_TO)

Engine ( ENGINE_ID, ENGINE_CC, ENGINE_Type )
```

Depending on how you think your data schema will change, you can either have an own table for motor-type, make and transmission or not. At the moment, I would recommend against having their own tables, because it would simply result in a table with one PK and one value.

The Manufacturer's and Engine's information, though, are more suitable in their own table.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful! Could you assist me with the relations to help with designing an ERD?

Comment: @Ryan No problem. I just changed it a bit to make it simpler. So your data model only consists of three tables. And basically they all have a 1:1 relationship.
If you have many data rows with same makes, you will possibly want to exclude 'Make' to an own table.

Comment: 1:1 ? this doesn't look like 1:1.

Comment: @ypercube: Ah you're right.
One Engine can have many models.
One Manufacturer can have many models.